# How can the number of observations be included as row to gtsummary?

Tags: r, gtsummary

I would like to show the number of observations not only in the table header, but also as the first row in the summary table. Background: I need this information in the body of the table, because it will be exported later as tibble to an excel table shell.

I currently use this workaround, that counts the number of IDs, but hope for a more elegant solution:

```
trial %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "ID")%>%
  mutate(ID = as.numeric(ID))%>%
  select(ID, age, grade, response, trt) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = trt,
    label = list(age ~ "Patient Age", ID ~ "Number of patients"),
    statistic = list(age ~ "{mean} ({sd})", ID ~ "{N_obs}"),
    digits = list(age ~ c(0, 1))
  )
```

[image: Wanted solution]